# Express require returning an empty object

Tags: node.js, express

Why is arrayFile an empty object when I console.log it in app.js?

Here is the app.js file:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var request = require("request-promise");
var path = require("path");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("views", path.join("./", "views"));

var arrayFile = require('./arrayFile.js');
```

Here is the arrayFile.js file. This will be a much bigger array once I can get the basics to work.

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your arrayFile.js you should use `module.exports = array`

So a short example would be something like this:

Here is your index.js (main):

```
const express = require('express');
const arrayFile = require('./arrayFile');

const app = express();

console.log(arrayFile);

app.listen(3000);
```

And here is your arrayFile.js:

```
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

module.exports = array;
```

Here is a live [demo](https://repl.it/@sarkism/DeliriousDefensiveInvocation)

Comment: @EricFunk Glad I could help... In general, if you want to import (require) a file you need to export it to make it available for import...